# AWS androidIoT : KEYSTORE_PATH location

Tags: aws-iot

AWS androidIoT :  Publish/Subscribe sample

Where to keep the "EYSTORE_PATH" file  while building the APK.

I have tried in `asset/aws/iot_keystore_aws` folder,
   but unable to the  get the folder path from `AssetManager`.

Sample  example has the path of :
KEYSTORE_PATH = context?.getFilesDir()!!.getPath()

Comment: Can you please provide the link of the example code?

Comment: Here the gitHub :https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub


I'm following the Using an off-device keystore

Steps 1:Import certificate and private key into PKCS12 keystore.
Steps 2:Convert PKCS12 keystore to a BKS (BouncyCastle) keystore.
Steps 3: List aliases in keystore to verify (optional).
Steps 4:Push to Android Emulator (optional).
 adb push <keystore name>.bks /data/user/0/your_app_dir_goes_here/files/<keystore name>
 
Note :  App is working perfectly , but how th pack the KETSTRORE file as part of the APK